# Extracting the days of week from a TV show in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list of the following TV Shows

```
(ABC)-(O)-(Mon-Fri)-(20:30-21:00)

(DEF)-(O)-(Mon-Sat)-(19:00-20:00)

(GHI)-(R)-(Mon-Tue,Thu-Fri,Sun)-(09:00-12:00)

(JKL)-(R)-(Mon,Wed,Fri-Sun)-(14:30-15:30)

(MNO)-(R)-(Fri)-(16:30-17:00)
```

The format is - ABC, DEF, so on are the show names, O or R is whether is the episode of the show is brand new or repeat telecast, Mon-Fri, so on are the days of the week on which the show is aired followed by the time of airing.

I was interested in using Regex in Python 3 to extract the days of the week for each show on which it is aired. Consider the show GHI: It's aired on Monday, Tuesday, not on Wednesday, aired on Thursday and Friday, not on Saturday and aired again on Sunday. The show ABC is aired on all days including Monday and Friday.

Thank you.

For GHI, the days of the week on which it is aired should be

```
TVShow["GHI"]["DaysofWeek"] = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Sunday"]
```

Comment: Regex is overkill for this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thought process:

1. First get the channel name and the days
2. Set the channel name as key in dictionary
3. Split the days by hyphen and record the ranges
4. Convert those days to integers value for iteration when there's a day range and create a list of ranges
5. Combined the list of ranges into one simple list
6. Match the day value with the full day list
7. Assign it to DaysofWeek key for the show

```
    import re

    def main ():
        shows = {}
        tvshows = '''(ABC)-(O)-(Mon-Fri)-(20:30-21:00)
                    (DEF)-(O)-(Mon-Sat)-(19:00-20:00)
                    (GHI)-(R)-(Mon-Tue,Thu-Fri,Sun)-(09:00-12:00)
                    (JKL)-(R)-(Mon,Wed,Fri-Sun)-(14:30-15:30)
                    (MNO)-(R)-(Fri)-(16:30-17:00)'''
        tvshows = tvshows.split ('\n')      # Break up new lines into a separate list
        for tvshow in tvshows:
            channel = re.findall (r'\((.*?)\)', tvshow)     # Regex return ['ABC', 'O', 'Mon-Fri', '20:30-21:00']
            shows.setdefault (channel [0], {})              # Set key to channel/tv show name
            shows [channel [0]].setdefault ('DaysofWeek', get_day (channel [2]))     # Assign 'DaysofWeek' as key and the show days as value
        print (shows)
        print (shows ['GHI']['DaysofWeek'])

    def get_day (show_days):
        day_ranges = []
        rangelist = []
        abbr_day = {'Mon': 0, 'Tue': 1, 'Wed': 2, 'Thu': 3, 'Fri': 4, 'Sat': 5, 'Sun': 6}
        full_day = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']
        show_days = show_days.split (',')       # Split by comma within show day
        show_days = [day.split ('-') for day in show_days]      # Split by hyphen.  Results:  [['Mon', 'Tue'],
                                                                # ['Thu', 'Fri'], ['Sun']]
        # Converting abbreviated days to integers
        for days in show_days:
            temp = [abbr_day [day] for day in days if day in abbr_day]  # Check show day matching abbreviated days, if
                                                                        # matches, get its corresponding integer value
            rangelist.append (range (temp [0], temp [-1] + 1))  # Combined everything into a list of range.
                                                                # Example:  [range(0, 2), range(3, 6), range(6, 7)]
        # Loop through the list of ranges and combine into one single list.  Example: [0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6]
        day_ranges = [j for i in rangelist for j in i if j not in rangelist]
        # Convert the integers value back to full day and put it in a list
        tv_days = [full_day [day] for day in day_ranges]
        return tv_days

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main ()
```

**Output:**

```
print ('shows [\'GHI\'][\'DaysofWeek\'] = ', shows ['GHI']['DaysofWeek'])
shows ['GHI']['DaysofWeek'] =  ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Sunday']
```